# fgets doesn't wait for the keyboard input

Tags: c

I want to read two strings from ther user's keyboard input, this is the code I tried :

```
char nomFichier[50], emp[100], empEtNomFichier[150];
printf("\nDonner le nom du fichier : ");
fgets(nomFichier, sizeof nomFichier, stdin);
printf("\nDonner l'emplacement du fichier : ");
fgets(emp, sizeof emp, stdin)
sprintf(empEtNomFichier, "%s/%s", emp, nomFichier);
```

The problem is when I run this code, the program doesn't wait for the keyboard input for the first `fgets()`, ad this is how the program looks :

```
Donner le nom du fichier : 
Donner l'emplacement du fichier : /home/ee/Desktop
/home/ee/Desktop
```

Comment: Can you post the shortest compilable example you can that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, please, see the modification I've made to my post

Comment: By "compilable" I mean including it in a `main()` function, `#include`ing the correct headers, and so on, something that can be just copied and compiled, and which produces your problem when you compile and run it. There may be something else in your current code causing it, creating a compilable example will help eliminate that possibility. If I just take your code and drop it into a `main()` function, for instance, I cannot reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is really that fgets() reads the terminating newline into the string.  Unless the buffer fills up, or EOF is encountered without a newline, the last character in the returned string will be '\n'.

Get rid of that by:

```
n = strlen(nomFichier);
if (n>0 && nomFichier[n-1]=='\n') { nomFichier[n-1] = 0; }
```

...and do the same for the emp string inside the if block.  There are also ways to use strtok with '\n' as a delimiter, or use sscanf with a "%xx[^\n]%*c" format, plus I'm sure others have different favorite solutions. ("xx" is the maximum string length, in decimal, in that scanf format.)

By the way, the other problem can't be portably addressed by fflush because fflush doesn't necessarily do anything.  GNU C implementations, for example, treat fflush(stdin) as a no-operation.

The problem is most likely due to a prior scanf() that read a value, but didn't read the newline. Programs that switch between token-oriented input (scanf/fscanf) and line-oriented input (fgets) must be prepared to deal with the leftover line.

The quickest fix is:

```
scanf("%*[^\n]%*c"); /* discard up to and including the next '\n' character */
```

...or the more direct:

```
int c;
while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') { }
```

Either way, I'd put that in a static function and let the optimizer decide whether to inline it or not.

You need to do that each time you switch from scanf() to fgets() input.

Comment: Thanks to whomever for the down-vote.  It not only reminded me to get back to this, but also got my measly rep off of palindromes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
char nomFichier[50], emp[100], empEtNomFichier[150];
printf("\nDonner le nom du fichier : ");
fflush(stdout);
fgets(nomFichier, sizeof nomFichier, stdin);
printf("\nDonner l'emplacement du fichier : ");
fflush(stdout);
fgets(emp, sizeof emp, stdin)
sprintf(empEtNomFichier, "%s/%s", emp, nomFichier);
```

stdout is line buffered so it will not output without a \n character -  try fflush();

Or try:

```
char buf[256]={0x0};
setvbuf(stdout, buf, _IONBF, 256);
```

Comment: I thought this, too, at first, but his problem is that too much stuff appears to be getting output, not too little. In any case, he said he tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: Okay - I missed where he tried fflush().  But that is one solution.  The other is to use setvbuf() to change stdout to unbuffered - not a great idea.  I'll add it.

Comment: Yeah, I deleted that answer and the comments. I'm not sure if he's doing something else in the code not being shown that's messing with the buffering.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me. I was able to get the behavior I was looking for like this:

Just make a throwaway variable and read the newline into it before the `fgets()`:

```
// . . . code above that leaves a \n in the stdin
char str[20];
char c;
printf("Prompt: ");
scanf("%c", &c);
fgets(str, 20, stdin);
printf("str = %s\n", str);
```

However, as the comment below points out, this isn't a clean "fix."

Comment: How does code know `scanf("%c", &c);` reads a _newline_ and not some other character? The prior read may have stopped for all sorts of reasons and not certainly at a `'\n'`.  Further, say there is no pending input at `printf("Prompt: ");` time, then if input is only `"\n"`, `scanf("%c", &c);` reads in the newline meant for `fgets(str, 20, stdin);`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yeah. I totally agree XD. my answer is less a solution than a temporary hack. I'll go back and edit it to make that clear. I just meant to share something that can help someone who needs to patch this weird thing really quickly before turning in something for school or something.

Comment: If you are concerned about throwing away a character that isn't a newline, could you not just check for that before deleting?

Comment: "could you not just check for that before deleting?" --> yes. 
IMO, rather than consume the left-overs (i.e. the `'\n'`) from the previous input function, better for the previous input function to read the entire line.  With `scanf()`, it is _possible_, but cleaner to eschew `scanf()` and just use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easiest way to fix the issue, and easy to understand for newbie . Do it 2 times :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char ch[50];
    char c;
    printf("Enter a random character: ");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(ch, sizeof(ch), stdin); // If you do this 1 time, it will not wait for your input
    fgets(ch, sizeof(ch), stdin);
    puts(ch);
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason the code snippet shown in the question isn't correct. The issue is obviously som