# concat two strings from keyboard input

Tags: c

I want to concat two strings from the user's keyboard input, and this is the code I tried :

```
char a[50], b[50], aAndB[100];
printf("\na : ");
fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);
printf("\nb : ");
fgets(b, sizeof(b), stdin);
snprintf(aAndB, sizeof(aAndB), "%s/%s", a, b);
printf(aAndB);
```

The problem is that the two strings are concatenated with a "\n", to be more clear, this is the output :

```
a : text1
b : text2
text1
/text2
```

but the output I'm expecting is :

```
a : text1
b : text2
text1/text2
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: The [accepted answer to the question you just asked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19073731/2399879) answered this.

Answer (score 0):

you can set remove the newline in string a by adding this before the snprintf() line.

```
a[strlen(a)-1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, fgets will read enter, you can use scanf instead, or change last character to 0 by hand, for example:
a[strlen(a)]='\0';